# Field homomorphism induces an isomorphism between their prime subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

So the question is:

> Let $\sigma$: $F_1 \xrightarrow[]{} F_2$ be a homomorphism where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are fields. Show $\sigma$ induces an isomorphism between their prime subfields and, in particular, the characteristics of $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the same.

This is an introduction to abstract algebra, all I really know about fields and homomorphisms are their definitions. That being said, in a previous exercise, I already proved injectivity for field homomorphisms in general as follows:

Note that for $\sigma$: $F_1 \xrightarrow[]{} F_2$, $\sigma(0_1) + \sigma(a) = \sigma(a)$, so $\sigma(0_1) = 0_2$, and similarly, $\sigma(1_1)\sigma(a_1) = \sigma(a_1)$, so $\sigma(1_1) = 1_2$.
For $a, b \in F_1$, assume $\sigma(a) = \sigma(b)$, but $a \neq b$. Then $\sigma(a-b) = \sigma(a) - \sigma(b) = 0$. However, as $a \neq b, a - b \neq 0$, so we can do $\sigma[(a-b)(a-b)^{-1}] = \sigma(1) = 1$. But then that implies $0 \cdot \sigma[(a-b)^{-1}] = 1$, which is a contradiction. Thus, if $\sigma(a) = \sigma(b), a = b$.

I've also attempted a proof for surjectivity:

Let $a_2 \in F_2 = 1_2 + 1_2 + ... + 1_2 = \sigma(1_1) + \sigma(1_1) + ... + \sigma(1_1) = \sigma(1_1 + 1_1 + ... + 1_1)$, so $1_1 + 1_1 + ... + 1_1 = a_1 \in F_1$ maps onto $a_2$.

Firstly, are these valid? If not, how can they be improved?
Secondly, these proofs don't really specify anything about the prime subfields, they just prove that there's an isomorphism between $F_1$ and $F_2$. I intuitively understand why there is an isomorphism between the prime subfields (because if $F_2$ loops back to 0, then $F_1$ must too) and that this implies that these fields have the same characteristic, but how can I formally state this in a proof?

Thank you so much for your help, and I'm sorry this post is a bit longwinded.

Comment: It seems one is assuming $\sigma$ is nontrivial, that is, that there exists $x$ in $F_1$ such that $\sigma(x)\ne0$. If not, then the conclusion is wrong.

Comment: @Gerry In this context, it would be unusual to not require homomorphisms to preserve the unit.

Comment: Yes I am assuming $\sigma$ is nontrivial, sorry for not specifying

Comment: @GerryMyerson, in my upbringing, a homomorphism between rings with unit must take unit to unit. This jibes well with the geometric interpretation of ring morphisms.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, the prime field of a field is its smallest subfield. It is also the subfield generated by $1$.

Since $\sigma(1)=1$, the image of the prime field of $F_1$ is a field contained in the prime field of $F_2$. It must therefore be the prime field of $F_2$.

Since $\sigma$ is injective because fields have no nontrivial ideals, $\sigma$ induces an isomorphism between the prime fields.